# What could be the reasons to configure LAN clients to use the server IP as DNS server in a domain controller Windows network?

Tags: domain-controller

This is rather a basic networking question, but I have found this configuration on several domain controllers with Windows Server, and I think ServerFault should be the proper site to ask.

What are the **reasons** to configure the **Windows Server machine as DNS Server** on LANs? Just DNS caching?

Assumptions:

- The Windows Server computer is not the router (with or without NAT) to access the internet. This is: there is a **dedicated internet router** (whether be it balance loader or not) on the LAN.

Answer (score 1):

AD is dependent upon and requires DNS. Windows AD clients need to locate Domain Controllers (among other things). They do this by querying a DNS server for the location (ip address) of a Domain Controller. In order for this to happen there must exist a DNS server or servers that host the DNS zone for the AD domain. This is most often (but not necessarily) a Domain Controller that is also a DNS server that hosts the DNS zone for the AD domain. This is why you see configurations such as the one you describe in your question.

It's not a requirement that a Windows DNS server host the AD DNS zone and it's not a requirement that a Domain Controller be a DNS server that hosts the AD DNS zone, but this is probably by far the most common configuration as it's the easiest to implement and support.

Comment: So Active Directory clients will not be capable of connecting to domain controller if its DNS configuration is set as automatic?

Answer (score 1):

The client's DNS configuration can be set as automatic, as long as the DHCP server (your router, I assume?) providing the configuration to the client gives the IP of the DNS server(s) associated with the Active Directory forest as the DNS server(s). Most often, the DNS IPs will be the domain controller(s). You will also want to set the default domain in the DHCP config, too (yourdomain.local for example).

Not doing the above will result in errors when trying to reach shares, joining a client to the domain, etc.

Comment: Indeed, the DHCP server is some router that knows nothing about the presence of a domain controller. But then: what happens with some computer (say, portable) that travels to another networks? Could its network config be left to obtain a DNS server automatically?

Comment: Yes. Leave DHCP enabled on the clients. Just make sure the DHCP server at the site with the Active Directory setup hands out the right DNS servers for the domain. You can usually edit the DNS servers a router hands out, overriding the default DNS servers it gives DHCP clients. If the router lets you set the default domain, set that to match the Active Directory domain, as well (not strictly necessary, but it saves having to type fully qualified domains when looking for local hosts (ie: you can ping dc, instead of dc.yourdomain.com).